# Leaving IT for another career - has anyone done it?

Tags: career-switch

After fifteen plus years of long hours and continuously being available 24x7 in an IT Support role I've come to the conclusion that I'm in need of a change, I just don't know to what.

Has anyone made the jump?  If so, to what?  Looking for inspiration.

Comment: I'd *start* by finding a better IT job, because there are certainly better IT jobs. Unless you are *very* well compensated (and maybe even if you are) it's not worth it to be on call 24x7. Until you work at a job that isn't b******t you will likely not have a frame of reference to know whether you really don't like IT or whether you just don't like being abused, and that matters because there are plenty of other industries that will also abuse you if you let them and many of them don't have as many exit options as IT.

Comment: Yes to @JaredSmith comment. Every profession has a potential for burnout/ "I've had it." IT (not my field at all) seems like  a broad profession. Your question for yourself should be "what kind of job do I want?" and see if there is something in IT that fits the answer.

Comment: I’ve known people who have left IT to refinish boats, to be a skydiving instructor, and to white river raft.  I’m not sure how that helps you though.  Maybe take a step back and retool this question into an actual problem you can be helped with.

Comment: I've also known people who have left well-paid IT to go off and pursue something that they *love doing* - being a ranger in a national park, a speciality baker, a paramedic. Their enthusiasm gets them through the inevitable difficulties. The fact that you don't know what you want to do is a bit of a red flag; you risk ending up in just another job that pays the bills, but starting again career-wise and with the same likely endpoint of wanting another change.

Comment: "If so, to what? Looking for inspiration." - that is way too wide. Stories of people doing it will not help you decide, unless they fit your profile AND fit your talent. Would it help you if I said I fired my clients as consultant and went on to make a million dollars per month trading? Unless you love that, AND can replicate it - it is a useless little tidbit story. This makes your question both, too wide and an awful fit for a Q&A site.

Answer (score 3):

**Lots of people have done it.  Also consider getting a better IT job**

I've been in IT for 12 years.  I've had your job (called constantly, always working late) - I quit, and got another job in IT.

**Finding another IT job where you'd be happier**

Start interviewing.  Say what you've said here - you're done with constant on call and all the late nights, but leave out the part about wanting to leave IT.  There are good IT jobs out there.

**Find a Non-IT job**

Exactly what else do you want to do?  You listed out the problems with your job, but you didn't list what you wanted.  I've known several people that got jobs waiting tables at a bar after doing IT for a while.

This let them make some money while they were figuring out something more permanent, and let them work on their people skills.